# How to sort List<jsonNode> alphabetically by a specific key using lambda .stream() in java

Tags: java, list, sorting, lambda, jsonnode

Below is the `JsonNode` which needs to be sorted alphabetically by key "size".

```
List<JsonNode> listOfSizes =[{"size":"CAL KING","SKU_ID":"68454463"},
                             {"size":"KING","SKU_ID":"68454456"},
                             {"size":"TWIN XL","SKU_ID":"68454425"},
                             {"size":"QUEEN","SKU_ID":"68454449"},
                             {"size":"FULL","SKU_ID":"68454432"},
                             {"size":"TWIN","SKU_ID":"68454418"}]
```

Expected result of sorting is :-

```
[{"size":"CAL KING","SKU_ID":"68454463"},
 {"size":"FULL","SKU_ID":"68454432"},
 {"size":"KING","SKU_ID":"68454456"},
 {"size":"QUEEN","SKU_ID":"68454449"},
 {"size":"TWIN","SKU_ID":"68454418"},
 {"size":"TWIN XL","SKU_ID":"68454425"}]
```

I tried doing below way:-

```java
listOfSizes.stream().filter(sku -> NotEmpty(sku.get("size"))).sorted();
```

It's not working. I also tried a couple more ways but didn't get expected result.

I am learning now lambda 8. Guys, please guide me if you know the exact logic for this because I do not want to do it in `foreach` way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [version of `sorted` that takes a `Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-):

```java
List<JsonType> sortedBySize = listOfSizes.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(jsonObject -> jsonObject.get("size"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Can't tell what your `JsonType` is, so you would have to substitute that in.

Comment: thank you so much! I tried the above code and replaced the JsonType to JsonNode but facing issue while doing .get()  , its saying "The method get(String) is undefined for the type String"

Comment: You would have to link to the JSON implementation you are using for me to answer this, but you can just check its documentation to see how to get a value from a JSON Object and use that method. One common pattern in JSON APIs is that they have different methods for different kinds of contained objects, i.e., `getNumber`, `getObject`, `getArray`, etc.

Comment: Thank you , getting Expected result now !!